# Sort the terms of expression by the given order?

Tags: differential-equations, sorting

Let's assume I have the following expression :

```
D[K[x,y],{x,1}] + D[J[x,y],{x,2},{y,2}] + D[U[x,y],{x,2},{y,1}].
```

Can we sort it by the order corresponding to given list of dependent variables.
For example in case of depVars = {J, U, K}, I need to get:

```
D[J[x,y],{x,2},{y,2}] + D[U[x,y],{x,2},{y,1}] + D[K[x,y],{x,1}].
```

Is it possible to write such sorting function ?

Comment: `Plus[]` is `Orderless`, so any sorting of terms would be mere pretty-printing.

Comment: I think it can be transferred into list by /.Plus->List in order to transfer back after sorting.

Comment: Sure, I'm just saying that no matter what you do, `b + a` will be converted to `a + b`.

Comment: Hmm, now got it. That's bad !!!

Comment: I tried. For Mathematica the priority is the derivation orders. So it is converted into :  D[K[x,y],{x,1}]  + D[U[x,y],{x,2},{y,1}] + D[J[x,y],{x,2},{y,2}]